# PHP - fwrite PHP Data With Set Variables

Tags: php, fwrite

I am trying to figure out how to fwrite into a .php file with variables given through $_POST, or $_GET, supplied by the user to set variables and such. So, how would I go about getting the below code to work so that instead of fwriting the code, insert a $_GET variable for example, or in the below description, being $derp.

```
<?php
$derp = "working!";
$something = '<?php echo "Well Thats {$derp}' ?>';
$file = fopen("worked.php","w");
if (fwrite($file,$something) > 0) {
echo "Fwrite Successful!";  
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: So you want the file to contain `<?php echo "Well Thats working!" ?>`?

Comment: So you want to generate PHP code from a query parameter? Why do you want to do this (incredibly unsafe) thing?

Comment: I know the security risks, this is going to be used to set things like Domain, database info, and other useful variables that will be limited for a CMS I'm trying to make for myself.

Comment: 1. Your quotation marks are all jacked up. 2. you need to learn the difference between `"` and `'`. 3. This is just an *unbelievably* bad idea.

Comment: @Sammitch Well then being being no help of any kind. How about you show me my wrong doings, so I can be a better PHP Programmer instead of downing my attempts to learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this use case looks very weird the following should work:

```
$data = array('<?php');
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = "\$$key = \"$value\";";
}
$data[] = '?>';

$data = join("\n", $data);
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.php', $data);
```

Beware: This code imposes several security risks.

**WTF is going on here?**

The above code iterates through all array elements of `$_GET` and `$_POST`, [combined](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).
By that it creates an array of lines to be written to a file.
This array will then be [`join()`](http://php.net/join)ed into a string by using the NEWLINE ascii character as the glue.

Assuming this script is called with the following query string:

```
?foo=bar&bar=baz
```

The file `/path/to/file.php` will then contain ([file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents)):

```
<?php
$foo = "bar";
$bar = "baz";
?>
```

The example above does not support nested query parameters like `foo[bar]=baz`.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how this works? I'm not familiar with file_put_contents. Could you use the variables I gave above?

Comment: added explaination, see above.

Comment: Thanks to all who attempted to help. But I figured it out. I'll take your word and say this one worked. Because I'm a nice guy. Screw Stack Overflow rofl.